# (Psalm 17:14-15 / Matthew 10:37 & Luke 14:26) Is Psalm 17 author saying seeking God's righteousness should be higher priority than earthly children?

Tags: psalms, new-testament, righteousness

In Psalm 17:14-15, it seems as if the Psalm 17 author is saying that the wicked are more satisfied with their children, and leave all their possessions to their children, and suggests that it is wrong.
Furthermore, The Psalm 17 author goes on to proclaim that his attention on God's face in righteousness, and be in God's Likeness(as in following God).

It just seemed strange to me that the Psalm 17 author is stating that the wicked are wrong to be satisfied with their children, and for leaving all their possessions with their children.

However, would it be correct to say that the Psalm 17:14-15 is basically similar to what Jesus Christ states in Matthew 10:37 and Luke 14:26?

> Psalm 17:13-15 New American Standard Bible (NASB)
>   13  Arise, O Lord,
>   confront him, bring him low; Deliver my soul from the wicked with Your
>   sword, 14  From men with Your hand, O Lord, From men [a]of the world,
>   whose portion is in this life, And whose belly You fill with Your
>   treasure; **They are satisfied with children, And leave their abundance
>   to their babes.  15  As for me, I shall behold Your face in
>   righteousness; I will be satisfied [b]with Your likeness when I awake.**
>
> Psalm 17:13-15 New King James Version (NKJV)
>    13 Arise, O Lord,
>   Confront him, cast him down; Deliver my life from the wicked with Your
>   sword, 14 With Your hand from men, O Lord, From men of the world who
>   have their portion in this life, And whose belly You fill with Your
>   hidden treasure.**They are satisfied with children, And leave the rest
>   of their possession for their babes.
>   15 As for me, I will see Your face in righteousness; I shall be
>   satisfied when I awake in Your likeness.**
>
> Matthew 10:37 New American Standard Bible (NASB)
>    37 “He who loves
>   father or mother more than Me is not worthy of Me; and he who loves
>   son or daughter more than Me is not worthy of Me.
>
> Matthew 10:37 New King James Version (NKJV)
>   37 He who loves father or
>   mother more than Me is not worthy of Me. And he who loves son or
>   daughter more than Me is not worthy of Me.
>
> Luke 14:26 New American Standard Bible (NASB)
>   26 “If anyone comes to
>   Me, and does not [a]hate his own father and mother and wife and
>   children and brothers and sisters, yes, and even his own life, he
>   cannot be My disciple.
>
> Luke 14:26 New King James Version (NKJV)
>   26 “If anyone comes to Me and does not hate his father and mother,
>   wife and children, brothers and sisters, yes, and his own life also,
>   he cannot be My disciple.

Comment: Should Adam leave an inheritance to Cain, or to Seth, or to both ? Should Isaac leave an inheritance to Esau, or to Jacob, or to both ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: My thought is that wicked parents leave their estate to wicked children and may cut out a godly child from their inheritance. So might a godly person choose not to pass on substance to progeny which has not followed in their footsteps. One has to make a will, it is only sensible. And in doing so, one can follow a righteous path.